# What needs to be changed in the human body in order to adapt it as best as possible to the harsh conditions of the desert?

Tags: science-based, biology, creature-design

Humans can not only survive, but even work in dry air up to 120 ° C (250 ° F) for a few minutes and up to some 70 ° C (160 ° F) for several hours if they have access to cool water.  In humid air, not much - at 100% humidity we cannot resist for any significant amount of time if the ambient temperature is above 35 ° C (95 ° F).  Our evaporative heat dissipation system works pretty well if the air is dry enough.  After all, we are mostly savanna animals.

However, during a long absence of water - it becomes a very valuable resource, which is why we need other modifications for long-term survival in the desert at temperatures above 50 ° C, because the skin does not produce any sweat - all the water is saved.

In short, what biological modifications do I need to give my genetically modified people in order to adapt them as well as possible to desert conditions at temperatures above 40-50 ° C, and the ability to protect themselves from the deadly heat of the sun and dry wind?

Note: I ask you not to add huge ears to them, since outwardly these superhumans resemble Gregham.

Comment: Not all deserts are hot, and even the ones that are hot are not hot all the time.  Indeed, they can become quite cold at night: https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/biome/biodesert.php  So your adaptation is simply to become nocturnal.  The far bigger problem is finding a food supply.

Answer (score 2):

In order to survive in a desert climate, humans would need to follow the same path explored by the [animals already adapted](http://www.primaryhomeworkhelp.co.uk/adaptations/desert.htm) to live there:

- deal with lack of water
- deal with hot temperatures

> Since water is so scarce, most desert animals get their water from the food they eat: succulent plants, seeds, or the blood and body tissues of their prey.
> How do desert animals prevent water from leaving their bodies?
> Desert animals prevent water leaving their bodies in a number of different ways. Some, like kangaroo rats and lizards, live in burrows which do not get too hot or too cold and have more humid (damp) air inside. These animals stay in their burrows during the hot days and emerge at night to feed.
> Other animals have bodies designed to save water. Scorpions and wolf spiders have a thick outer covering which reduces moisture loss. The kidneys of desert animals concentrate urine, so that they excrete less water.

[Additional adaptations](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/znxsgk7/revision/2) can be:

- develop more slender bodies, in order to increase the surface to volume ration and facilitate the heat loss.
- grow an insulating fur
- larger feet to limit sinking in the sandy ground

Comment: You can describe these modifications in more detail from an anatomical point of view.

Comment: @FrenchThompson3 Bergmann Law. Just Apply the Bergmann laws: Tall, slender, dark skin color to stop UV-light or a light fur coat to reflect light. Also: Large ears to vent heat (fennec!)

Comment: you forgot the temperatures of the night, which are quite cold

Answer (score -1):

a better circulatory system, to regulate the temperature, the feet would probably have protective tissue not to burn the feet away, and a way to also contain heat with the fur at night, and because they are genetically modified, i add them being both hot and cold blooded, our eyes would be modified to take less damage from light, and our skin would also be modifed along with the hair, to get as much water in and the least out

Comment: If you want to contribute, please tell us the nature of these modifications in as much detail as possible, preferably while reading other people's answers so as not to repeat yourself. At the moment, you have said already well-known things ( I already know this ).

Comment: Please either delete your answer or write more